# Change java compiler version

Tags: java, javac

I get this error when running my `Java` application

```
Global : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

When I checked my `Java` version, I found that it was different from the compiler version

```
java -version
# java version "1.7.0_65"
# OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.1) (7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.2)
# OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
javac -version
# javac 1.8.0_20
```

How do I downgrade the Java compiler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open a console. Type

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

After entering your root password you can enter the number of a javac with "java-7" in its name.

Edit: You could also `update-alternatives --config java` to choose a newer JVM that is compatible to Java 8 bytecode.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to downgrade the compiler; you just need to tell the compiler to produce classes that a Java 7 JVM will understand.  Use the options `-source 7 -target 7` when running `javac`.

Comment: This is documented at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-example.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you are using linux,

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Then you can type your choice. If you get message like 'There is only one alternative...' then you should type to the terminal

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/(your java home)/bin/javac" 1
```